# highcharts: set max value of yaxis issue

Tags: highcharts, max

see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k0hrz224/2/

i want the max value of the yaxis to be `100`. currently, as you can see, it is `150` and i dont know why, because i explicitly set `max: 100` of this yaxis.

i know that changing (on line 101)

```
 min: -25
```

to

```
min: 0
```

seems like a solution. however i need `min: -25` because i want to display `A` and `B` as it is shown in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i managed to do it. i "hardcoded" the ticks on my own:

```
tickPositions: [-25, 0, 25, 50, 75,100]
```

then i experienced the desired behavior, i.e., no wrong autoscaling of any axis.

Comment: You can also use [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner), then calculate ticks by function.

Answer (score 1):

Things can get a little odd when you have multiple y axes.

Add this to your chart:

```
chart: {
   alignTicks:false  
}
```

Which will stop the different axes from trying to resolve with each other, and stop your axis at 100.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/k0hrz224/4/

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks

Comment: hm, thanks for your help. however in my real-code (not jsfiddle) i still have a problem, that after hiding the D series, the max of the yaxis somehow gets changed to 150 again. and i dont know why. i tried to reproduce it in jsfiddle and to get the same behavior i had to make the graph smaller. but please try it. hide column D and then make it visible again and then the max of yaxis suddenly changes to 150. why is that? http://jsfiddle.net/k0hrz224/6/

Comment: I am not seeing that issue when I try (latest firefox). I would try setting the maxPadding to 0 on the axis as well.

Comment: hm yes, you are right. on firefox i also dont see the issue in jsfiddle. however, i have the issue in firefox in my "real app" which i am not able reproduce in the fiddle :/ maxPadding=0 also does not help. i've created an animated gif to show you the strange behavior: i load the graph, then click on the "recall" series label to disable it, and suddenly yAxis changes to a max of 150. maybe you have another idea what i could try. here's the gif: http://i.imgur.com/PEJ5uV6.gif

Comment: Try to set [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval) as 25 or 50. If it will not solve problem, use [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner)

Comment: finally i managed to do it. i "hardcoded" the ticks on my own: `tickPositions: [-25, 0, 25, 50, 75,100]`. then i got the desired behavior, i.e., no wrong autoscaling of any axis.